# display(df.limit(10)) does not always work in synapse notebooks

Tags: azure-synapse, spark-notebook

Within synapse notebooks, running display(df.limit(10)) does not always work.
It usually works when the notebook is first run, but after a while, if i run it again, it does not display the df.

The server has not died or timed out, code is still executing.

The code cell runs, no errors are thrown, it simply does not display the data.
I dont know at what point, or what has changed to stop it displaying and am asking if anyone has experienced this.

as there is no error, I don't have any further to provide but if there is something I should check please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: if you have not defined a schema, chances are that display() is going to fail in certain cases. try df.show(10) and see whether it's working?

Answer (score 1):

Especially in Synapse you should rather use *Df.show()*. If you have any issues in the way it displays your data, just copy the output and paste it into notepad++.

Using *display()* may end in a browser crash and needs way more capacity than e.g. databricks notebooks.

Keep in mind,that synapse is still Partially in preview. When I have the issue, you describe, I really use *Df.show()* and there you go, it works.